# Leaflet autoPan not panning enough vertically

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have popups on markers activating successfully and autoPan is set to true by default. The map is panning successfully horizontally to ensure a popup is visible when the marker is close to the edge of the map. It is panning vertically (down), but not enough. Its like it thinks the map is taller than it is. Or thinks more of the map is visible than actually is. The result is the popup is not fully visible. I could pad the pan, but I would like to figure why its not panning enough by itself. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you could share an online example of the described unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Well - I created a JSFiddle but I can't reproduce the issue. Application has so many layers of abstraction, hard to figure out. Trying to use a getBounds() or something to figure out if the map is overflowing off page but is not visible. Will report back. Thanks.